# Find grid control inside grid without its rowbound event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid of list of companies & below its branches(subgrid within company grid). I have checkbox for each binding with their id's(Companyid & branchid).I have one button to add those selcted values from either company or branch & show all selected record in another grid.Add button is outside of gridview so on click of add button i have to find branch gridview here i can find its parent grid.I wrote following code to find control inside onclick event of add button but its not finding that control:

> `GridView gvbranch= (GridView)gvcompany.FindControl("gvbranch");`

So please help me how i can find that child control in add click event?
Thanks

Comment: Is the grid static, or databound?

Comment: have you tried this and what did you get?

Comment: i have rowdatabound to bind data...i got null value when i tried to find branch control in add click envent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txt = row.Cells[0].Controls[0].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
        string value = txt.Text;
        Response.Write(value);
    }
```

use something like this , on button event

Comment: same problem finds null value